# No member function declared in class - error with basic compile

Tags: c++, header, compiler-errors

Getting this error when compiling a basic class and header. Not sure if I'm missing something obvious? Can provide any additional details if needed.

Note: I added `#include <string>` in Event.h and the error remains.

Event.cpp

```
#include "Event.h"
#include <string>

std::string Event::getLabel() {
    return label;
}
```

Event.h

```
#ifndef EVENT_H
#define EVENT_H

#define EVENT_STOP 0
#define EVENT_START 1


class Event {
private:

protected:
    double time;
    std::string label;
    int type; // EVENT_START OR EVENT_STOP

public:
    std::string getLabel(); 

};

#endif
```

compile and error

```
g++ -c -Wall -pedantic correngine.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -pedantic CSVManager.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -pedantic ServerEvent.cpp 
g++    -c -o UPSEvent.o UPSEvent.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -pedantic CorrelationEngineManager.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -pedantic Event.cpp
Event.cpp:4: error: no ‘std::string Event::getLabel()’ member function declared in class ‘Event’
make: *** [Event.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem, and solved it by removing the [header name].gch file that had been generated next to the header, and which apparently had been corrupted. Maybe you can try that?

Comment: +1: This is the first thing to check, and ends up working so often that it just isn't funny... (well, ok, so maybe it is a *little* bit funny)

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to do this without manually deleting files? Like the `clean` or `rebuild` options in some IDE-s or compilers, which scrap every temporary or intermediate files and start over, exactly to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include `std::string` header in Event.h

```
#ifndef EVENT_H
#define EVENT_H

#include <string>        //<<----  here

#define EVENT_STOP 0
#define EVENT_START 1


class Event {
private:

protected:
    double time;
    std::string label;
    int type; // EVENT_START OR EVENT_STOP

public:
    std::string getLabel(); 

};

#endif
```

Comment: you include it at wrong place, include it in Event.h file not Event.cpp

Comment: I definitely included it in the header. I put it in both files, too.

Comment: That's interesting, I compiled your code with `#include <string>`, then the error message goes away in my environment. I don't see any reason it fails if you include necessary headers.

Comment: I changed the types to int and the same error is appearing (replacing int with std::string), so that wasn't the issue.

Comment: @user2089851: My guess would be that there is another unrelated `Event` class in scope that is confusing the compiler. Try changing the name of your class to something else. If the error persists, then something screwy is going on.

Comment: I changed all the related files to use EventA and it compiles correctly, does this mean there is already an Event class?

Comment: My code is small so it's either something that's included with C++ or not my class. I noticed an Event.h.gch file which I just deleted, is that something relevant?